# split('\n') doesn't work in the browser but works in jsbin

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing the code that is supposed to parse the text. The first step is to split it into array of lines. I do it with: `let lines = input.split('\n');` Function I wrote works perfectly when tested in jsbin but it doesn't work when tested in the browser. In the browser input is passed from the text input to the component but when logged into console looks fine. What might be the case?

input: `'\\page 1 \n\ page 1.1'`

Code:

```
function parseTree(input) {
  if (input === '') {
    return '';
  }
  console.log(input)
  let root = {title: null, isRoot: true, children: [] };
  let lines = input.split('\n');
  console.log(lines);
  /* ... */
  return root;
}

parseTree('\\page 1 \n\ page 1.1');
```

in jsbin the result is (first line is input, second `lines` array):

> "\page 1   page 1.1"
>
> ["\page 1 ", " page 1.1"]

( https://jsbin.com/yacuhot/edit?js,console )

while in browser console it's:

> \page 1 \n\ page 1.1
>
> ["\page 1 \n\ page 1.1"]

Comment: which browser? also, I tested on chrome 65 and the output is the same for both jsbin and browser console.

Comment: Chrome 66. That's strange... Looks like problem might be somewhere else?

Comment: I found the problem. Instead of input text I have to use textarea to support multiple line. Still I cannot use explicit '\n' in one line (instead of using enter to break the text) which I would like to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

text from input containing `\n` is not line break , it has no special meaning ..

consider it as escaped version of it and hence your split will not work on it.

as it is escaped `split('\\n')` should work but thats not what you want.

to have true new line in your input you want to use `textarea` element instead